# Trying to connect to an inner server in PyCharm (to use a remote interpreter)

Tags: ssh, pycharm

i would like to connect to a remote server to run my code with PyCharm. the thing is this server is only accessible through another server (it is an inner server), but PyCharm does not allow connecting to a server through another server (in the add python interpreter - ssh interpreter section), is there any way i can connect to an inner server in PyCharm?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm supports ProxyCommand in OpenSSH config (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21629). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216017 for example configuration.